# How to define a name for paragraphs referenced by \autoref

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, sections-paragraphs

I have defined the following command:

```
\newcommand*{\namerefLabeled}[1]{\nameref{#1} (\autoref{#1})}
```

It largely does what it's supposed to, i.e. turning something like:

```
For further details, see \namerefLabeled{sec:cleancode}.
```

into

> For further details, see Clean Code (section 1.2.3).

However, if I reference a label **within a paragraph**, it does not choose the desired section naming. See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\namerefLabeled}[1]{\nameref{#1} (\autoref{#1})}

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \label{A}
        \subsection{B}
        \label{B}
            \subsubsection{C}
            \label{C}
                \paragraph{D}
                \label{D}
    \section{where stuff is referenced}
    For reference, see \namerefLabeled{A}, \namerefLabeled{B}, \namerefLabeled{C} or \namerefLabeled{D}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

**Does someone know how to fix this issue, e.g. by defining an autoref-name for paragraphs, if that's possible? My guess is there is no value set for it, and so it chooses (what I assume to be) the default labeling name "section".**

Using `\renewcommand\paragraphautorefname{paragraph}` did not solve it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This said, I'd guess that you just need `\renewcommand\paragraphautorefname{paragraph}`.

Comment: MWE added. Your suggestion did not solve the issue, though (thanks nevertheless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not `paragraph`, you will have the same problem e.g. with `\subsection*`. When the sectioning command is not numbered, it is always registered as a unnumbered section. To change this you have to patch some internal macros: Insert in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\currenthrefautoname{}
\newcommand\criticalhrefautoname{section*}
\newcommand\currentsectioningcommand{section}
\let\@StartSection\@startsection
\def\@startsection#1{%
  \edef\currentsectioningcommand{#1}%
  \@StartSection{#1}%
}
\let\HY@MakeCurrentHrefAuto\Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto
\def\Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto#1{%
  \long\edef\currenthrefautoname{#1}%
  \ifx\currenthrefautoname\criticalhrefautoname%
    \edef\currenthrefautoname{\currentsectioningcommand*}%
  \fi%
  \expandafter\HY@MakeCurrentHrefAuto\expandafter{\currenthrefautoname}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'm having difficulties comprehending why someone would know these commands, but it solves my problem. Here, have a cookie * gives cookie *

Comment: I noticed that my original desire actually doesn't make that much sense, since no "paragraph 1.2.3" exists - "1.2.3" would be a subsubsection. Could your code snippet be changed to print out the corresponding name for whichever section's number is listed? I.e. referencing an unnumbered paragraph within a numbered subsubsection would print "paragraphname (subsubsection 1.2.3)"?

Comment: @PixelMaster Of course, but I think you should either edit the question or ask a new one then, otherwise the new answer will not fit the question.

Comment: I figured. I think I'll just replace `\autoref` with `\cref` - that just uses the same label for everything (in englisch, probably "section". Since I'm german, everything gets called "Abschnitt").

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\paragraph` (or more precisely `\@sect`) does not call `\refstepcounter` when the TOC will not include these entries.  This can be fixed by changing the `secnumdepth` counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\namerefLabeled}[1]{\nameref{#1} (\autoref{#1})}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \label{A}
        \subsection{B}
        \label{B}
            \subsubsection{C}
            \label{C}
                \paragraph{D}
                \label{D}
    \section{where stuff is referenced}
    For reference, see \namerefLabeled{A}, \namerefLabeled{B}, \namerefLabeled{C} or \namerefLabeled{D}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: while that indeed solves the problem, I would rather have "paragraphs" called "sections" than numbering them. Thanks nevertheless :)

Comment: \label uses whatever the last call to \refstepcounter saved in \@currentlabel, \@currentlabelname and \@currentHref.  \@currentlabelname could easily be set to "equation" or "page" instead.